# How can I close an accordion on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion, expand

I have an accordion using just HTML and CSS (no JS).

For desktop, I hover over to expand, and remove the mouse to close the panel.

For mobile, I click to expand, ***but clicking on the same object doesn't close it***. I have to click on the white space to close the panel, which isn't intuitive.

QUESTION: How can I write this code so I click on the accordion to close the panel?...is JS the only way?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="slider-containers">

<!--effect #1 -->
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="flexbox-slider flexbox-slider-1">
    <div class="flexbox-slide">
      <div class="img-overlay"><div class="start">ENGAGE<span id="accordion-expand">+</span></div>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1464213/pexels-photo-1464213.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=500" alt="Slide Image" class="panel-img">
      </div>

      <div class="text-block">
        <h3>Engage</h3>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-slide">
      <div class="img-overlay">
        <div class="start">EDUCATE<span id="accordion-expand">+</span></div>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1350615/pexels-photo-1350615.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=500" alt="Slide Image" class="panel-img">
      </div>
      <div class="text-block">
        <h3>Educate</h3>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-slide">
      <div class="img-overlay">
        <div class="start">EMPOWER<span id="accordion-expand">+</span></div>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1093913/pexels-photo-1093913.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=500" alt="Slide Image" class="panel-img">
      </div>
  <div class="text-block">
    <h3>Empower</h3>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
$slider-height: 500px;
$text-block-width: 400px;

$dark-font-color: #212121;
$accent-font-color: #CA9CE1;
$light-font-color: #fff;
$text-overlay-color: #000;
$text-overlay-opacity: 0.6;
$slide-overlay-color: #fff;
$slide-overlay-opacity: 0.6;

//transitions and mixins

//transitions mixin
@mixin transition-mix($property: all, $duration: 0.2s, $timing: linear, $delay: 0s) {
  transition-property: $property;
  transition-duration: $duration;
  transition-timing-function: $timing;
  transition-delay: $delay;
}

//position absolute mixin
@mixin position-absolute ($top: null, $left: null, $right: null, $bottom: null) {
  position: absolute;
  top: $top;
  left: $left;
  right: $right;
  bottom: $bottom;
}



.container {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;


}

  .link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 30px auto 0;

    a {
      @include transition-mix;

      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      margin-right: 40px;
      color: inherit;
      font: {
        size: inherit;
      }
      text-decoration: none;

      &:hover {
        color: $accent-font-color;
      }

      &:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
      }

      i {
        color: $accent-font-color;
        margin-right: 9px;
        font-size: 30px;
      }
    }
  }

.slider-containers {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 60px  ;
}

.slider-container {
  margin-bottom: 60px;

  h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.flexbox-slider {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.flexbox-slider {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: $slider-height;
  visibility: hidden;

  .flexbox-slide {
    @include transition-mix($duration: .3s);

    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: skewx(-8deg);

    //overlay
    &:after {
      @include position-absolute($top: 0, $left: 0);
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba($slide-overlay-color, $slide-overlay-opacity);
      z-index: 2;

      opacity: 0;
    }

    img {
      @include position-absolute($top: 50%, $left: 50%);
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .text-block {
      @include position-absolute($bottom: 30px, $left: 30px);
      max-width: $text-block-width;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: rgba($text-overlay-color, $text-overlay-opacity);
      color: $light-font-color;

      z-index: 4;

      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;

      h3 {
        font: {
          size: 20px;
          weight: 700;
        }
      }
    }
  }

    &:hover {

    .flexbox-slide:hover {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
}

/* effect  */
.flexbox-slider.flexbox-slider-1 {

  .flexbox-slide {

    .text-block {
      bottom: 60px;
    }
  }

  &:hover {

    .start {visibility:hidden}

    .flexbox-slide:hover {

      .text-block {
        @include transition-mix($delay: .5s);
        bottom: 30px;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
  }
}

.start {font-weight: bold; color: #fbaf17; font-size: 150%; z-index:1000;  padding: 45% 20%; 
}
img.panel-img {height:500px !important; }
.img-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(51,85,153,.9);
}

.flexbox-slide {border-right: dashed 4px gold;}
.flexbox-slide:last-child {border-right: 0px}

#accordion-expand, .slide-bottom {visibility: hidden}


@media (max-width:960px) {
  .flexbox-slider {
    flex-direction: column; 
    height: 200px;

    .flexbox-slide {
      margin: auto;
      width: 75%;
      height: 200px !important;
      transform: skewX(0deg);

    } 
    .flexbox-slide {border-right: none;}
  }
  #accordion-expand {float:right; visibility: visible}
  .start {margin: 0 20px; padding: 20px; border-bottom: solid 2px  gold;}
}
```

**[Here's my codepen](https://codepen.io/SnowboardBruin/pen/WPWLzj)**

Comment: Well CSS can't capture a click so in general no. The reason it works with the hover to open is that mobile devices often see a `:hover` and interpret it as a click. Typically the way you represent a "click" in CSS is by using a togglable hidden HTML elelement like a `input type="checkbox"`. Then apply one style when it's checked and another when it isn't. JS is likely a much better solution in your case.

Comment: BTW, I'm impressed with how far you got with pure CSS!

Comment: As @BryceHowitson mentions, you can use a checkbox to acheive the 'click' effect, but it will be a pain to maintain here. Here is a sample of it being used for controlling a nav menu. https://codepen.io/evelo2/pen/djpzWR

Comment: @Bibberty Thanks for linking that! I didn't have an example handy.

Comment: I tinkered with this one, but was not the author. Its a nice widget for sure.